# tailwind css customize breakpoints AND customize container max-width

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Using tailwind and cannot figure out why this does not work properly. I want to set specific breakpoints that have nothing to do with the container max-widths. Is this even possible inside the tailwind config? I want the "screens" inside the container object to be those max-widths when they reach the corresponding breakpoint.

```
export default {
  theme: {
    screens: { //breakpoints
      xs: '415px',
      sm: '576px',
      md: '768px',
      lg: '992px',
      xl: '1200px',
    },
    container: {
      center: true,
    screens: { //container max-widths at given breakpoint
        xs: '100%',
        sm: '540px',
        md: '720px',
        lg: '960px',
        xl: '1140px',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Tailwind does not offer this kind of configuration with regards to the `container` built-in class.

As alternatives, you could consider:

- Using the template engine (if the project is utilizing one) to create a container component with the desired `max-w-*` classes and screen variants.
- Creating your own `container` class, either in CSS or via a custom Tailwind plugin. You could name the class something slightly different to avoid conflict of Tailwind's `container` class, or you could disable the `container` core Tailwind plugin if you want to use the `container` class name.

Comment: Yes I already went down the route of creating my own container class but it felt a bit dirty too me lol. Thanks for the input! :)